# Convert and order timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, time

I have a pandas df column of timestamps that contain HH:MM before midnight and HH:MM:SS after midnight. Eventually I want to sort these values.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['08:00','12:00','24:00:00','20:00','16:00','26:00:00'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I can't add :00 to the column as some it will return:

```
df['A'] = [x + ':00' for x in df['A']]

             A
0     08:00:00
1     12:00:00
2  24:00:00:00
3     20:00:00
4     16:00:00
5  26:00:00:00
```

My intended output is:

```
          A
0  08:00:00
1  12:00:00
4  16:00:00
3  20:00:00
2  24:00:00
5  26:00:00
```

Comment: Is it always `:00` or can you have `20:02` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string slicing:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str[:5] + ':00'

print(df)

          A
0  08:00:00
1  12:00:00
2  24:00:00
3  20:00:00
4  16:00:00
5  26:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `np.where` in case 24:00:01 in your data

```
np.where(df.A.str.len()==5,df.A+':00',df.A)
Out[187]: 
array(['08:00:00', '12:00:00', '24:00:00', '20:00:00', '16:00:00',
       '26:00:00'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression with **`str.replace`**:

```
df.A.str.replace(r'(^\d+:\d+$)', r'\1:00')

0    08:00:00
1    12:00:00
2    24:00:00
3    20:00:00
4    16:00:00
5    26:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

One more answer to the pile (add the seconds only to the short strings):

```
df.loc[df["A"].str.len()==5, "A"] += ":00"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works even if you have some thing like `24:00:04` (i say this because it won't just directly change it to `24:00:00`):

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['08:00','12:00','24:00:04','20:00','16:00','26:00:00'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df['A'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x.split(':'))==3 else x+':00'))
```

Output:

```
0    08:00:00
1    12:00:00
2    24:00:04
3    20:00:00
4    16:00:00
5    26:00:00
Name: A, dtype: object
```